# @Keep method will it be obfuscated

Tags: java, android, kotlin, proguard, android-proguard

**@Keep**

From the following document, I just wonder even it is not minified. Will a method name be still obfuscated ??

> Denotes that the annotated element should not be removed when the code
>   is minified at build time. This is typically used on methods and
>   classes that are accessed only via reflection so a compiler may think
>   that the code is unused.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/Keep

**Example of using keep on unused method (Kotlin)**

```
@Keep
fun SendToGroup(message: String?) {
    fireNotification(
            title = "Notify All",
            message = message ?: "")
}

@Keep
fun SendToAndroid(message: String?, signalRId: String?) {
    fireNotification(
            title = "Notify Group",
            message = message ?: "")
}
```

Comment: As the documentation says it won't be obfuscated. If obfuscated, it can't be accessed via reflection. The documentation even recommends to use for methods or classes accessed only via relection

Comment: yes, make sense thank you.